# Who was G. H. Hardy's Tripos coach?

Tags: biographical-details

There is conflicting opinion as to who was Hardy's Tripos coach. The Wikipedia page on Hardy claims it was R. A. Herman, a claim that appears to be backed up by Leonard Roth in his article "Old Tripos days" that appeared in the *Monthly* in 1971 (78, pp. 223-236). However, Titchmarsh claims that he was first coached by R. R. Webb, and later by A. E. H. Love (Obituary in the first volume of Hardy's *Collected Papers*). As Titchmarsh was one of Hardy's students, I would take his word as final. Do I have this right? Does anyone have knowledge of who the *real* coach was?

Comment: The MacTutor history of mathematics page also lists R. R. Webb as Hardy's initial coach. This page seems to follow Titchmarsh's obit and the preface to the *Apology* by C. P. Snow.

Comment: Kanigel's _The Man who Knew Infinity_ says it was Webb and later Love. There are no footnotes but Titchmarsh's obituary is listed in the bibliography

Comment: @Spencer - Thanks for the info. Someday, I need to get a copy of that book. In his *Apology* preface Snow says that "He was sent to a famous coach, to whom most potential Senior Wranglers went." Judging from what I have read, at the time Hardy took the Tripos that would have been Webb. Thanks again. Stay safe and healthy.